# Redirect WebService

Tags: web-services, redirect

I want to redirect my webservice A to another webservice B. So, i set the redirection in IIS.  However, consumers of my webservice A get an error while accessing the webservice because they get a 302 message; and they dont handle it. I dont want to force all my consumers to change their code to handle this.  I dont want to change my webmethods to make them a wrapper to call webservice B.

What are my options?

Comment: What platform, technology and version are you using? Java vs. .NET? WCF vs. ASMX? .NET 2.0 vs. .NET 3.5 SP1?

Answer (score 1):

Just trying to understand.

You have a new webservice.  The old web service is being shut down.  You want them same URL to go to the new webservice.

Are the two services hosted on the same box?  Also, are the method's / interfaces the same between the two services?

If so, don't do an IIS level redirect. Instead, just bind the URL of the old service to the new service's IIS settings.

If not, then you need to tell your users that you are shutting down the old service, give them a time period on when it will happen that is long enough for them to make the appropriate changes.  Then, on that day, turn the old service off.

Comment: 1.the two services are hosted on different boxes.  
2.the methods/interfaces are the same between the 2 services.
3.the intention is to eventually shut down the old service, but i need to give enough time (in the interim) i need to do something

Comment: If you're redirecting all of the clients, it seems like you should just make a DNS change to point to the new box.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the possibility to change the dns records you could write a webservice with the same signature that just calls your new webservice and returns the result of your new webservice.